# Create an Azure VM with an unmanaged disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-gov

I'm trying to **create an Azure VM with an unmanaged disk via PowerShell** since managed disks aren't supported in Azure Government yet.

None of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-powershell) I could find for PowerShell VM creation references managed or unmanaged disks and the default seems to be managed disks. My VM creation fails with the following error:

> New-AzureRmVM : Managed Disks are not supported in this region.
>
> ErrorCode: BadRequest

Here's the script I'm using:

```
$location = "USGovTexas"

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name myResourceGroup -Location $location

# Create a subnet configuration
$subnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name mySubnet -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24

# Create a virtual network
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -Name MYvNET -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 -Subnet $subnetConfig

# Create a public IP address and specify a DNS name
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -AllocationMethod Static -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4 -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)"

# Create an inbound network security group rule for port 3389
$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  -Protocol Tcp `
    -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow

# Create an inbound network security group rule for port 80
$nsgRuleWeb = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleWWW  -Protocol Tcp `
    -Direction Inbound -Priority 1001 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange 80 -Access Allow

# Create a network security group
$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP,$nsgRuleWeb

# Create a virtual network card and associate with public IP address and NSG
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name myNic -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

# Define a credential object
$cred = Get-Credential

# Create a virtual machine configuration
$vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName myVM -VMSize Standard_DS2_v2 | `
    Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName myVM -Credential $cred | `
    Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer `
    -Skus 2016-Datacenter -Version latest | Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id

# Create the virtual machine
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vmConfig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use this script to create Azure windows VM with unmanaged disk:

```
$location = "USGovTexas"
$rgname = "myResourceGroup"
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name myResourceGroup -Location $location

# Create a subnet configuration
$subnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name mySubnet -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24

# Create a virtual network
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -Name MYvNET -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 -Subnet $subnetConfig

# Create a public IP address and specify a DNS name
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -AllocationMethod Static -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4 -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)"

# Create an inbound network security group rule for port 3389
$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  -Protocol Tcp `
    -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow

# Create an inbound network security group rule for port 80
$nsgRuleWeb = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleWWW  -Protocol Tcp `
    -Direction Inbound -Priority 1001 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange 80 -Access Allow

# Create a network security group
$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP,$nsgRuleWeb

# Create a virtual network card and associate with public IP address and NSG
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name myNic -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location `
    -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

# Define a credential object
$cred = Get-Credential

#VM config
$vmsize = "Standard_DS2"
$vmName="myVM" 
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize
$pubName = ”MicrosoftWindowsServer”
$offerName = ”WindowsServer”
$skuName = ”2016-Datacenter”
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName $pubName -Offer $offerName -Skus $skuName -Version "latest" 
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $NIC.Id 

# Create a new storage account
New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -AccountName "MyStorageAccount" -Location $location -SkuName "Standard_LRS"

# Disk setup
$diskName = ”jason-disk”
$storageaccount = "jasontest321"
$STA = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $storageAccount
$OSDiskUri = $STA.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $diskName? + ".vhd"
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $diskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage 

# Create the virtual machine
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vm
```

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations. Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need further assistance.