# How to create and attach a Unmanged disk in Azure VM through powershell scripts?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to attach 1 TB of unmanaged data disk in Azure VM (Data base server). VM is already created using unmanaged disk. Can't figure out the powershell command to do it.

VM has already been created using unmanaged disks, VM already have 5 unmanaged disks of 400GB each. I need to add 1TB disk as I'm running out of space. **Just need to add another disk**.

Comment: The was was to create and add **Data Disk** to an existing VM. Question is not answered in other post @4c74356b41.  This question should be reopen

Comment: what do you mean? you cant add another os disk. @Hannel

Comment: I mean @Amit's question was not answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307612/create-an-azure-vm-with-an-unmanaged-disk.  That post has nothing about data disk.